# 1 domain, 2 IPs

Tags: domain-name-system, email

Hy Guys!

I have a problem here.

I have a domain in a host just to send e-mails. Now I have to publish a website(asp.net-mvc-3) in the same domain, but in a different host.

Ask: How can I have the same domain (www.domain.com) in 2 different hosts?

Tks.

Comment: Your lack of information....disturbs me.

Comment: isn"t this why [MX records](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MX_record) are used?

Comment: Guys, do you want me to put here where I host my sites? Do you wanna the login and password to? It is a generic question. I'm not an expert in servers and hosts and I didn't know where to start. So, keep "playin" serverfault and collecting points.

Answer (score 1):

Edit your DNS zone to name your mail host `mail.example.com` and your web host `web.example.com` (or something similar).

Answer (score 0):

If all the first host is doing is email sending, then setting `www.example.com` and `domain.com` to the second host is no problem. If the first host is also receiving email then this is what you use [MX records](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MX_record) for. The `MX` record will take care of routing the email while you point the main `A` record to the web server. If the first host also has webservices or something for checking your email then I'd probably use a sub-domain for that such as `mail.example.com`.

If you have different webservices on each server and want both under the `www.domain.com` namespace then you probably want to setup a [reverse proxy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy) on one of the hosts.

Also it's no problem to create an `A` record with both IP addresses. However this is probably not what you want for this situation. You would do that to do [simple load balancing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_DNS).